# In Unity 3D, what does console error ".dll was not registered" mean?

Tags: unity-game-engine, dll

I just installed Unity 2019 and attempted to convert 2018 projects. I get this error on the console. What does this mean, and what is required to fix it? I do not understand how to register an extension

Extension /Applications/Unity/Hub/Editor/2019.3.0a5/PlaybackEngines/Facebook/SDK/7.9.4/Facebook.Unity.dll was not registered, that means it relies on default UnityExtensions settings, please register extension and apply necessary settings for it in the callback.

Extension /Applications/Unity/Hub/Editor/2019.3.0a5/PlaybackEngines/Facebook/SDK/7.9.4/FacebookNamedPipeClient.dll was not registered, that means it relies on default UnityExtensions settings, please register extension and apply necessary settings for it in the callback.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to upgrade to unstable Alpha version of Unity.

If you don't need alpha features then try to upgrade to latest stable version of Unity. Currently it is Unity [2019.1.6](https://unity3d.com/unity/whats-new/2019.1.6).
If you'll still have problems then update your [Facebook SDK to 7.16.0](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/unity/downloads).

If you need special or experimental functionality that presents only in Alpha version then you shall report a bug in [Unity Issue Tracker](https://unity3d.com/unity/qa/bug-reporting).